# Does PatternSyntaxException can have many causes?

Tags: java, regex, exception

**What erroneous regexp could produce PatternSyntaxException that has many causes?**

`PatternSytanxException` **IS-A** Throwable and has method `.getCause()`. While making application to print nice messages on `SQLExceptions` and `PatternSyntaxExceptions` I've found that some other exception `SQLException` can have many causes. In Java tutorial [it is said](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html) that

> A SQLException instance might have a causal relationship, which consists of one or more Throwable objects that caused the SQLException instance to be thrown. To navigate this chain of causes, recursively call the method SQLException.getCause until a null value is returned.

I'm wondering whether `PatternSyntaxException` anywhere is thrown so that **chain of causes** is specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the JDK `PatternSyntaxException` is only created by the private method `Pattern.error` and within `Pattern` no call site sets the cause of `PatternSyntaxException`. So currently `PatternSyntaxException` will not have a error cause when thrown by the `Pattern` class.

(But this does not prevent someone to create `PatternSyntaxException` and set a cause).

Comment: ty. you are referring to jdk8?

Comment: @Willmore as far as I can see this holds for jdk7 and jdk8